# Adobe Air - Application updater

Tags: air

Is it possible to skip the Adobe Air application updater *[check for updates](http://www.stratulat.com/blog/wp-content/update-ui1.gif)* window to start the search for updates directly?

This is my code that launches the *check for updates* window:

```
applicationUpdaterUI.addEventListener(UpdateEvent.INITIALIZED, applicationUpdaterUI_INITIALIZED);
applicationUpdaterUI.initialize();  


function applicationUpdaterUI_INITIALIZED(event:UpdateEvent):void {
applicationUpdaterUI.checkNow();
}
```

Thanks. Uli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add before initialization:

```
applicationUpdaterUI.isCheckForUpdateVisible = false; // We won't ask permission to check for an update
```